# .NET Core - Error 'NETSDK1067' during publish

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a problem with a dotnet core project of mine. I have a TFS build that does a "dotnet publish" and deploys the application to IIS.

The publish command looks like this:

```
dotnet publish -o $(build.stagingDirectory) -c Release --self-contained --runtime win81-x64
```

My code hasn't changed but now I get the following error when I run the build on the TFS:

```
NETSDK1067: Self-contained applications are required to use the application host. Either set SelfContained to false or set UseAppHost to true.
```

We updated the build server to the newest .NET Core SDK last week so I guess it probably has something to do with that.

What changed and what can I do to make the build work again?

Comment: do you have a global.json file a the root level of your solution ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Comment: No I don't have a global.json on my root level. Until now this wasn't necessary.

Comment: So you can add it to target the previous SDK you installed. There is an open issue on github regarding this : https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2505 maybe you'll find a workaround